# Create ARRaycastQuery from 3d object

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am developing an app using ARKit and SceneKit.

Is it possible to create raycast query using ARRaycastQuery from an object in the scene?

### [image: Scene]

As per the picture above, I am trying to cast a ray from [3d object] and find a plane in that direction.

This is what I am trying:

```swift
    let location = objectNode.simdWorldPosition
    let startRayPoint = simd_float3(location.x, location.y, location.z + 2.0)
    let endRayPoint = simd_float3(location.x, location.y, location.z - 2.0)

    let query = ARRaycastQuery(origin: startRayPoint, direction: endRayPoint, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
    timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        if let result = self.sceneView.castRay(for: query).first {
            print("castRay result: \(result)")
        } else {
            print("failed to cast ray")
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the location of the [object] and start ray from 2m away and direction to 2m forward by manipulating the 'z' axis. However, the query always fails, what am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using ARKit you can implement 3 different ray-casting methods**:

- raycast(_:)

> This instance method checks once for intersections between a ray (the ray you create from a screen point you're interested in) and real-world surfaces.

- raycastQuery(from:allowing:alignment:)

> This instance method creates a raycast query that originates from a point on the view, aligned with the center of the camera's field of view.

- trackedRaycast(_:updateHandler:)

> This instance method repeats a raycast query over time to notify you of updated surfaces in the physical environment.

But as I see you need to implement a method that creates a ray from one 3d object that must hit another 3d object in a scene. In that case you need to implement a RealityKit's instance method that can be used inside ARView's scene:

```
raycast(from:to:query:mask:relativeTo:)
```

> **This method performs a `convex ray cast` against all the geometry in the scene for a ray between two end points**.

```
func raycast(from startPosition: SIMD3<Float>, 
                 to endPosition: SIMD3<Float>, 
                          query: CollisionCastQueryType = .all, 
                           mask: CollisionGroup = .all, 
     relativeTo referenceEntity: Entity? = nil) -> [CollisionCastHit]
```

In real code it might look like this:

```
import RealityKit

let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(from: [2, 2, 2], 
                                                          to: [9, 9, 9], 
                                                       query: .all,  
                                                        mask: .all, 
                                                  relativeTo: nil)

guard let rayCast: CollisionCastHit = raycasts.first
else { return }

print(rayCast.entity.name)
print(rayCast.distance)
```

But remember!

**The method ignores entities that lack a [CollisionComponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/collisioncomponent)**. So, before using aforementioned method you need to assign collision shape for a future hit-model.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. So it is not possible to do it with `ARRaycastQuery(origin:direction:allowing:alignment:)`? do I have to change to RealityKit instead of ARKit?

Comment: As official documentation suggests: `func raycast(_ query: ARRaycastQuery) -> [ARRaycastResult]` – Ray casting provides a 3D location in physical space that corresponds to a given 2D location on the screen.

Comment: It's strange that `ARRaycastQuery(origin: simd_float3, direction: simd_float3...` init has `simd_float3` type for `origin` argument... And yes, I suppose you have to use RealityKit view instead of SceneKit (if it's not critical in your case).

Comment: That's why I was confused because `ARRaycastQuery` initializer receives two `simd_float3` which is `origin` and `direction` so I was assuming it is two points in the 3d scene and `raycastQuery(from:allowing:alignment:)` is a convenience function that receives screen coordination into 3d point and direction to forward.

Comment: I think it would be better to use RealityKit anyway, I will test it with RealityKit about this. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly saying I'm not 100% sure 3D-raycasting is impossible in ARSCNView. But I didn't meet it before.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this question while looking for a solution for my problem. I found a possible mistake in OP's code:  the second parameter for raycast is direction and NOT position. If you want it to point to +z direction the vector should be: (0,0,1), which should be the second parameter. So the raycast query should look like:

```
let query = ARRaycastQuery(origin: startRayPoint, direction: simd_float3(0,0,1), allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
```

I have not tried it myself, came to this conclusion from apple's doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arraycastquery.

In the doc, it says that direction is the trajectory for raycast but not end point as the OP was providing.